# Is it possible to configure/improve the AJAX search in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mediawiki

Our company has an internal MediaWiki installation with a page called "Our Spamfilter". When typing into the search bar, suggestions show up below it in real time (see the [`$wgEnableOpenSearchSuggest`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableOpenSearchSuggest) setting.)

Unfortunately, when typing out `spamfilt...`, the AJAX search box fails to suggest the article. It only suggests it if you type out `our spa....`. Basically, what you type has to match the title of the article exactly from left to right.

This is already causing confusion as people assume the page doesn't exist if they type "spamfilter" and get no suggestions.

Is there a reasonably simple way (a setting or plugin) to improve the AJAX search box? When I say "improve", I mean that typing "spam" at least has to suggest the "Our Spamfilter" page.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the [`SpecialSearchResults`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SpecialSearchResults) hook or mess with the JS code, but it is much simpler to just make a [redirect](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Redirects) from `Spamfilter` to `Our Spamfilter`.